# Improve query speed in MySQL with no indexes/primary keys/unique fields

Tags: mysql, optimization

So, I've this database (almost non relational, since it has no primary keys, unique fields, foreign keys, etc) and every time I've to restart a C client it does this query:

`select * from table where table.id1 = another_table.id1 and table.id2 > another_table.id2 limit 1;`

With 9 million rows in the first table and 800 in the second, it takes forever to complete :/

I'm not a SQL developer, so my knowledge in this field is very limited. Sure this problem might sound silly, but right now I'm in a dead end...

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the database to run any faster unless you have given it something to work with -- meaning, you **need** to add an index to get it to run more quickly. It will be insanely faster once you do.

Comment: Adding indexes may kill insertion performance and we need to do this massively at run time.

Comment: Adding indexes *may* kill insert performance. Not adding them obviously *definitly* kills query performance. Sorry, there is no magical option you can turn on to improve query performance. There are only indexes ;).

Comment: It's true, indexes _may_ definitely slow insertion. It sounds like a give-and-take; if you need that initial startup to be fast, then indexes are pretty much the only way to go for a query like that. If insertion performance is too hindered for you, you need to look at changing the server configuration or adding hardware.  Here's an article about [speeding up MySQL](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/A_1250-3-Ways-to-Speed-Up-MySQL.html), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason there are no indexes, pk, etc? Cause that's exactly what's missing to get decent performance here. Also, are another_table.id1 and another_table.id2 joins with tables or fixed values (in the former case: how does the sql really look?).

Answer (score 0):

Usually indexes are there to improve performance on that kind of queries, so if your think that indexes may kill your insert performance, maybe an option is to have the indexes defined, but disabled and enable the indexes when that `select` is done, something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE table ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE other_table ENABLE KEYS;
select * from table where table.id1 = another_table.id1 and table.id2 > another_table.id2 limit 1;
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE other_table DISABLE KEYS;
```